# Ubuntu Touch app with c++ core and QML interface. How to create?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, c++, qml

How to create Ubuntu Touch application with c++ core? In examples I see only pure QML apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create Ubuntu touch applicaion with c++ core with UI in QML follow following steps:

1. Open `Qt Creator`
2. Press `ctrl`+`n` to create a new project
3. Choose project as `Applications`
4. select `Qt Quick Application (Built-in Elements)`

This will create a project with UI in QML and core in c++ there will be directory in project directory named `sources`. It will contain `main.cpp` to start your application which will be loading the `main.qml`.