# Howto create a new C++ based Ubuntu touch project in Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, c++

There is no option to start a **C++ and QML** based project in Ubuntu SDK. 
It only offers to create a QML project with no C++ codes.

If I try to add C++ classes to the QML project, I get this error:

[image]

Please provide guidance to initiate a C++ based Ubuntu Touch project in Ubuntu SDK.
Thank you!

Comment: Where is the file located? In the same folder or somewhere else?

Comment: in the same folder, I forgot to say it

Comment: You can use C++ for the logic and QML for the UI. It's really easy to export QObjects from C++ side to the QML side.

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this problem?

Comment: Personally I lost interest due to too many troubles (Ubuntu Touch delay releases, so no phones, SDK bugs, no emulator - back in time -, and other things), maybe I'll recheck when the Development Tools will be more stable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Touch app with c++ core and QML interface. How to create?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/278990/ubuntu-touch-app-with-c-core-and-qml-interface-how-to-create)

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. Its actually related to the permissions. Try to lauch utouch using the 'sudo'. Hope It would help if its the same as mine

Comment: Or do a sudo chown youruser:youruser /location/of/project. This is better because then you dont have to run the program as su which may corrupt your entire system should an error occur