# Ubuntu SDK: QML with C++ recommended App Design Methodology

Tags: application-development, c++, ubuntu-sdk, qml

1. Are there documented general guidelines for mixing QML with C++ for ubuntu apps?
2. "QML for UI design and C++ for logic" seems to be the trend. Is this the right way forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [QML](https://askubuntu.com/tags/qml/info) wiki page. You'll find a link that will guide you to write apps mixing QML and C++:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html

In addition to this tutorial check the following questions:

- [Ubuntu Touch app with c++ core and QML interface. How to create?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278990/ubuntu-touch-app-with-c-core-and-qml-interface-how-to-create)
- [Embedding C++ Objects into QML with Context Properties](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431368/embedding-c-objects-into-qml-with-context-properties/431458#431458)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With regards to point 2 in my question, is it better to restrict c++ only to logic or should it be used to handle the UI dynamically as well. What do you suggest based on experience?

Comment: @user3490458: You can manage/create UI elements from C++ (Qt Quick allows this kind of thing) but I would restrict c++ to logic as such operations are a difficult to maintain.