# Cannot run QML App with C++ plugin

Tags: ubuntu-touch, c++, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm trying to extend a QML App with C++ functionality. Basically I want to make the MythMote app which is available on Android available on Ubuntu Touch. Also see my other question for which I would still appreciate some answers/pointers ([Ubuntu Touch App with Simple UI (QMake) - how to connect C++ to QML](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568067/ubuntu-touch-app-with-simple-ui-qmake-how-to-connect-c-to-qml)). I found a tutorial on extending QML with C++ (http://www.ics.com/blog/integrating-c-qml) and I'm trying to use that as my starting point.

Therefore, in the SDK, I chose QML App with C++ plugin (qmake), chose ubuntu-core-15.04 framework and the Ubuntu Device (GCC armhf-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-vivid) as well as Desktop kit.

Running the app as is (no modifications) as a desktop app works.

Running on device (Nexus 4) fails with first a dialog saying that it found some build errors in current task, and asks if I want to ignore them.

The issues are:

```
warning: security_policy_groups_safe_app (debug): (REJECT) reserved policy group 'debug': not for production use
The debug policy group is automatically injected and should only be used for development.
To create a package for the store use the publish tab!

error: security_policy_version_matches_framework (app/app.apparmor): 1.2 != 1.3 (ubuntu-core-15.04)
```

I concentrated on the error and changed the app.apparmor file so that policy version reads 1.3.

It then fails:

```
Cannot install /tmp/untitled.username_0.1_armhf.click: Framework "ubuntu-core-15.04" not present on system (use --force-missing-framework option to override)
```

The device has the GCC armhf-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-vivid kit. Should this be changed and if so, how can I do so? Auto-creating a kit re-creates the GCC armhf-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-vivid kit.

Comment: I realized that the kit on the device is not easily changed. So I guess that I now need to somehow match the framework to the kit on the device. No idea how I should do this as yet.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the correct combination was QML App with C++ plugin (**cmake**) with the framework ubuntu-sdk-14.10-utopic.

Comment: I will try if the cmake option works.

Comment: I can confirm that creating the app using cmake does work. Thanks Velkan.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to create a QML App with the C++ plugin and use the **qmake** option you will not be able to install the app on a device. The error:

```
Framework "ubuntu-core-15.04" not present on system
```

Therefore, in the SDK, choose QML App with C++ plugin (**cmake**). It will then run on your device.